# How to use list.sort in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I would like to use the following line in Android Studio:

`list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(map -> Integer.parseInt(map.get("Score"))));`

The problem is, this is Java 8 code and Android Studio doesn't support Java 8. Could I add a line to the Gradle Dependencies to import these functions?

Comment: what JDK have you installed?

Comment: i don't think android supports java8 ... but I'm not sure

Comment: @PhilippSander JDK 1.7.

Comment: "Could I add a line to the Gradle Dependencies to import these functions?" -- assuming that the `Comparator` that you are using is `java.util.Comparator`, then no, that is not possible.

Comment: you can't add content from the java 8 sdk directly into android. However, you can use `Collections.sort`, and implement a `Comparator`. And you can use retrolambda to get the java 8 lambda syntax.

Comment: Well, thats not quite right. Android studio does support Java 8 (JDK1.8), Maybe not fully but like 98% is supported.